# Find if exists Supremum and Infimum for the set A:

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Hi im having difficulties with this problem

> Let$\{({a_n})_{n \in N}\}$ be  a   sequence  defined  by 
>   $${a_n}: = 4 - \frac{9}{n}$$
>   Find  if  exists  infimum, supremum  for  the  set
>   $$A: = \{ {a_n}^2 - 3{a_n} - 10:n \in N\} $$

I dont know how to start, i tried to replace the sequence $a_n$ on the set, and analize the set as a function. To find max, min, so i can detect critical points.  But i dont think is the way to do solve it.

Comment: What did you get when you replaced $a_n$ on the set?

Comment: @zxcvbs Welcome to MSE. Two answers to your question were posted (first the one using calculus, and then one with little calculus). Please note you could vote (up or down, hopefully up:) one or more answers, and you could accept one of the answers (this both gives points and marks the question as being not only answered, but with an accepted answer). Yes, you could analyze this as a function (as in the answer by Rory Daulton who posted it first). As a matter of taste you could also do it without calculus (just solving an algebraic inequality to determine the sign), as in an alternative answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have benefited from reading @RoryDaulton answer, but I prefer to do the same thing over without using derivatives (although the OP seems to be fine with derivatives, just not sure if this is the way to solve it ... why not).

So $A: = \{ b_n:n \in N\}$ where $b_n={a_n}^2 - 3{a_n} - 10$ and $a_n=4-\dfrac9n$.
Note $a_{n+1}-a_n=\dfrac9{n(n+1)}$

Let $d_n=b_{n+1}-b_n=a_{n+1}^2-a_n^2-3(a_{n+1}-a_n)=$
$=(a_{n+1}+a_n)(a_{n+1}-a_n)-3(a_{n+1}-a_n)=$
$=(a_{n+1}+a_n-3)(a_{n+1}-a_n) = $
$=\bigl(4-\dfrac9{n+1}+4-\dfrac9n-3\bigr)\bigl(4-\dfrac9{n+1}-(4-\dfrac9n)\bigr)$.
After further simplification we get $d_n=\dfrac{5n^2-13n-9}{n^2(n+1)^2}$.

We want to know when $d_n>0$ and when $d_n<0$. It is enough to look as the sign of the numerator $5n^2-13n-9$ (which as a function of $n$ is a parabola opening up, could not resist the word function after all, and involve calculus:)

Solving $5n^2-13n-9=0$ we get $n_{1,2}=\dfrac{13\pm\sqrt{349}}{10}$. Ignore the negative root. The positive root, say $n_1$, is between $\dfrac{13+18}{10}$ and $\dfrac{13+19}{10}$ (since $18^2=324<349<361=19^2$), hence $\dfrac{31}{10}<n_1<\dfrac{32}{10}$, and in integers 
$3<n_1<4$. (Hope this agrees with the results you get when you compute the derivative as a function of a real argument, as suggested in the first posted answer.)

We get that $d_n<0$ when $1\le n\le 3$ and $d_n>0$ for $n\ge4$ (ignoring what happens when $n\le0$).
Since $d_n=b_{n+1}-b_n$ it follows that $b_1>b_2>b_3>b_4$ but $b_4<b_5<b_6<b_7<\cdots$.

It follows that $\inf_n b_n=\min_n b_n=b_4=a_4^2 - 3a_4 - 10=\dfrac{-195}{16}$.

$\sup_n b_n$ would be the larger of $b_1=\bigl(4-\dfrac91\bigr)^2-3\bigl(4-\dfrac91\bigr)-10=25+15-10=30$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\Bigl(\bigl(4-\dfrac9n\bigr)^2-3\bigl(4-\dfrac9n\bigr)-10\Bigr)=16-12-10=-6$.
That is, $\sup_n b_n=\max\{30,-6\}=30$.

Comment: The OP used the tag "calculus" and mentioned critical points, so I concluded that he is fine with derivatives. Your answers do agree with mine. Your method nicely uses a quadratic polynomial, so congratulations on a great answer. My answer seems more straightforward for those who know calculus--a matter of taste. The level of the OP's stated work and the tone of his request led me to only give hints and outline and avoid giving the final answers.

Comment: @RoryDaulton The OP did say "critical points" (obviously calculus) but also said "i don't think is the way to do solve it" so the message feels a bit ambiguous. Your calculus solution did very clearly show what is going on in this problem, and it is only a matter of taste, that I wanted to do it in a "more discrete" way. Your answer was posted an hour ago, and the OP was not seen for 2 hours, so I guess we are just enjoying each others solutions. (I do want to see every little detail of the solution.) Perhaps the only advantage in my solution (if any) is that we need not evaluate $b_3$.

Comment: @RoryDaulton concerning the exact numbers and detailed answer, I computed them by hand, usually making mistakes, and correcting them only after using computer algebra system [reduce](http://reduce-algebra.com/)

Comment: Hi great answer, im lost in this step   
:=(an+1+an−3)(an+1−an−3)−3(an+1−an)==(an+1+an−3)(an+1−an−3)−3(an+1−an)=
=(an+1+an−3)(an+1−an)=
Which factorization technique did you use? 
This approach is new to me, and much more cleaner than calculus.

Comment: there were typos, sorry, no wonder you were lost, I corrected it, thank you @zxcvbs (I just used difference of squares, and then factored out $(a_{n+1}-a_n)$ ) will read your own answer and comment later, need to go to work now. P.S. Thank you for accepting my answer, you perhaps know that apart from accepting one answer you could vote (up or down :) more than one answer

Answer (score 2):

**OUTLINE:**

Substitute the expression $4-\frac 9n$ for $a_n$ into the expression $a_n^2-3a_n-10$. This will give you a function

$$f(n)=\left(4-\frac 9n\right)^2-3\left(4-\frac 9n\right)-10$$

Simplify that function expression.

Treat it as a function of real numbers $f(x)$ and take its derivative. Use that derivative to analyze the function $f$. You will find that it has a minimum at a particular positive non-integral number (let's call it $b$), is decreasing for $0<x<b$, and is increasing for $b<x$.

Therefore the minimum of that function over the positive integers is one of the two integers closest to $b$. Just calculate the function at those two numbers $\lfloor b\rfloor$ and $\lfloor b\rfloor+1$ to find the minimum value and its location. That is the desired infimum.

The function $f(x)$ is decreasing for $0<x<b$, so the maximum of $f$ for all integers in that interval is $f(1)$.

The function $f(x)$ is increasing for $b<x$, so the supremum of $f$ for all integers in that interval is the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $+\infty$. That limit is easy to find.

The supremum of $f$ over all positive integers will be the larger of those last two numbers.

Comment: It might be interesting to supply the details and compare with answer by OP. Here you replace $n$ with $x$ and get $f(x)=\frac{-6x^2-45x+81}{x^2}$ and $f'(x)=\frac{45x-162}{x^3}$ with $f'(x)>0$ when $x>\frac{162}{45}=3.6$ (ignoring $x<0$). So min at either $f(3)=-12$ or at $f(4)=-12.1875$. On the other hand OP @zxcvbs replaced $a_n$ with $x$ to obtain $f(x)=x^2-3x-10$, $f'(x)=2x-3$ (a much easier derivative). Although OP's approach looked awkward to me on first reading (I wouldn't have thought of it) it is correct and works, and involves easier calculus (as well as solving an extra inequality)

Comment: @Mirko: That derivative is easy if you rewrite it $f(x)=-6-45x^{-1}+81^{-2}$, so $f'(x)=45x^{-2}-162x^{-3}$. Wasn't that easy? Solving $f'(x)=0$ is also easy. And yes, those are the numeric answers I got.

Comment: of course you are right, I should have known better (I do teach my students that they should simplify before they apply the quotient rule so the latter could perhaps be avoided:) but it just was easier to take the derivative without thinking, as I plugged it into an online derivative calculator. Hopefully I would have noticed the easier form of $f(x)$ if I had computed it myself, instead of asking my computer to "simplify" it. Well, ok no excuses, I should have noticed when I saw the result, but I overlooked, and yes, it is easy when done right. You meant $f(x)=-6-45x^{-1}+81x^{-2}$, thank you

Answer (score 1):

excuse my delay. I tried to solve it with the tools i know.

\begin{array}{l}
Let{({a_n})_{n \in N}}\,\,{a_n}: = 4 - \frac{9}{n}\,\,A: = \{ {a_n}^2 - 3{a_n} - 10:n \in N\} \\
\,4 - \frac{9}{n} > 0\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,4 > \frac{9}{n}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,4n > 9\,\,\,n > \frac{9}{4}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,n\, > 0\,\,\forall \,n > 2\\
4 - \frac{9}{{n + 1}} > \,4 - \frac{9}{n}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, - \frac{9}{{n + 1}} + \frac{9}{n} > 0\,\,\,\,\frac{9}{{(n + 1)n}} > \,0\,\, \to \,\,{a_n} \nearrow \\
Supr({a_n}),\,Inf({a_n})\\
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \,\,\,4 - \frac{9}{n}\, = 4\,\,\, \to \,\,{a_n} < 4\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,{a_1} = 4 - \frac{9}{1} =  - 5\,\\
Supr({a_n}) = 4\,\,\,\,\,\,\,Inf({a_n}) =  - 5\\
{a_n} \in [ - 5,4)\\
A: = \{ {a_n}^2 - 3{a_n} - 10:n \in N\} \\
f(x) = {x^2} - 3x - 10 = (x - 5)(x + 2)\\
f'(x) = 2x - 3 = (x - 3/2)\\
Min = 3/2\,\,\,\,1 \le 3/2 \le 2\, \to \,1 \le {a_{n\,}} \le 2\\
\,1 \le 4 - \frac{9}{n} \le 2\,\,\,\,\, \to \,\,\,\,\,3 \le n \le 9/2\,\,\,\,\,n \in N\, \to n = \left\{ {3,4} \right\}\,\,\\
 - 5 < {a_n} < 4\,\,\,\,\,\,f( - 5) = 30\,\,\,\,\,\,\,f(4) =  - 6\,\,\,{a_3} = 1\,\,{a_4} = \frac{7}{4}\\
 - 6 < f({a_n}) < 30\\
f({a_3}) = \,f(1) =  - 12\,\,\,f({a_4}) = \,f(\frac{7}{4}) =  - 12,81\,\,\,f(1)\, \in \,N\\
Supr(A) = 30\,\,Inf(A) =  - 12\,\,
\end{array}
Using that the sequence is increasing and bounded between [-5,4).
I just had to analize critical points in the set between f(-5),f(4).
I tried to solve for, \begin{array}{2}f(x) = {(4 - \frac{9}{n})^2} - 3(4 - \frac{9}{n}) - 10\end{array}
I tried this in the exam, but i made a mistake, somewhere.
Thanks, for all the answers. 
Mirko approach is new to me, and much more simpler.

Update 12/03
I asked in class for some justification questions. My analysis is valid only for the increasing  of the set $$A: = {\rm{\{ }}{{\rm{a}}_n}^2{\rm{ - 3}}{{\rm{a}}_n}{\rm{ - 10:n}} \in {\rm{N\} }}$$ So i have to find n in ${{\rm{a}}_n}$ using the critical point value, in that case both ${{\rm{a}}_n}$ and $A$ are increasing, and can be its behaviour analyzed. Before the critical point i have to get values by hand for $$A({{\rm{a}}_1}),A({{\rm{a}}_2}),A({{\rm{a}}_3}),A({{\rm{a}}_4})$$Since one function is decreasing, and the other increasing. I also have to do lim->inf  A(an),to get the extreme of the composition.

Comment: your approach is correct. Shortcut: $\frac1n$ is decreasing and so is $\frac9n$, hence $\frac{-9}n$ is increasing, and so is $a_n=4-\frac9n$. Towards the end you have a typo, $f(\frac{7}{4}) =  - 12,81$ should be $f(\frac{7}{4})=-12,1875$ (which is the same as $-\frac{195}{16}$). Also, since $-12,1875<-12$, the conclusion should be that $Inf(A)=-12,1875$, not $-12$. It seems to me you discarded $-12,1875$ because it is not in $N$, but it is not required to be in $N$ (at least this is not stated in your problem, and by default $Inf$ is taken in the reals) so I think $-12,1875$ is correct answer

Comment: $f'(x)=2x-3=2(x-3/2)$ though this this does not change the rest of the solution. Of course the equation $2x-3=0$ is equivalent to the equation $x-3/2=0$, but this does not mean that $2x-3=(x-3/2)$. Finally, you wrote your whole answer as one long math formula, and it might have been easier to write several shorter math formulas, each enclosed in dollar signs (and with spaces and more text in between, and perhaps more commas). But I do not really have objections, your answer is good, it makes sense, and you found a correct approach on your own which is great. Thank you for posting this question